# convert tree to another tree with new format in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to convert on tree to another tree with different type ,about 1 week i tried the different solution but i didn't successful, please help me.
my code is :

```
type (a',b') Tree = Lead of a'| Noeud of b'*a'*(a',b')Tree list
type strTree = st of int | Leaf of String | Tree of string *Strin* strTree list
val Tree-strTree :(a'->string)->(b'->string)->(a',b')Tree -> strTree

let Tree-strTree p pp a =
   let rec mapA a' = match a' with
     | Lead _ -> Tree ("","",[])
     | Noeud (f,r,l)-> Tree(p f ,pp r ,fold_left(fun x y->x @ [mapA y])[] l)
   in
   mapA  a
```

> Error: unbound value fold_left

I don't Know how i can use fold_left

Comment: Format better your code. At least four spaces in front of every code line

Comment: "but i didn't successful" is not a clear problem statement. Please see [ask]. Your code is also rife with typos.

Comment: i would to say that's my code doesn't run and i have the error

Answer (score 1):

There is a `fold_left` function in the `List` module. You just need to give the name of the module:

```
List.fold_left (fun x y -> ... )
```

However, as others have noted there are many other problems with your code, at least as you have shown it here.

Comment: It possible say me how i can write my code because i blocked for do that, thank you